# Link to a page inside Sammy.js website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sammy.js

I am using Sammy.js for my website and I want to send a link to a page on the website to someone in an email.  I have set up links like this:

```
this.get('#/', function(context) {
  $("#main").load("sections/home.html");
});

this.get('#/:page', function(context) {
  $("#main").load( "sections/" + this.params['page'] + ".html" );
});
```

The first one is default, so that when you type in my website, it goes to the home.html section first and if I take that out, when I go to my website, nothing loads in `#main`.  Now, if I were to just type into my URL bar `mywebsite.com/#/contact`, it will load `mywebsite.com/#/`, in other words, straight to the home page.

I will say that if I go to the homepage first, `mywebsite.com/#/`, and then modify the URL to the page I want, it will work.  If I hit enter to reload the page, or if I try to modify it again, it will go back to the homepage. Please help.

Comment: Also, I am using a little AJAX jQuery later if that might be interfering.  Although I think I was having the problem before then anyways.

Comment: Are you defining your routing and calling run('#/') in $(document).ready()?

Comment: I start the main.js code like this
    `Sammy('#main', function() {
      $("#header").load("templates/header.html");
      $("#nav-bar").load("templates/nav-bar.html");
      $("#footer").load("templates/footer.html");`
then the code above, then end like this:
`}).run();`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a document.ready and run the default route - like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    Sammy('#main', function() { 
            $("#header").load("templates/header.html"); 
            $("#nav-bar").load("templates/nav-bar.html"); 
            $("#footer").load("templates/footer.html");

            this.get('#/', function(context) {
              $("#main").load("sections/home.html");
            });

            this.get('#/:page', function(context) {
              $("#main").load( "sections/" + this.params['page'] + ".html" );
            });

    }).run('#/');

})
```

That seems to work on my end.

Comment: Hey rivarolle, thanks for this.  I have tried it but I'm still not able to type a page into the address bar and have it load the right page, anything else you might be doing differently?